# Elastic search for word developer finds development

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search, so I have one beginner question :)
I am searching for word "developer", however Elastic returns not only developer, but also "development". I wonder how it could be? I know that the SOUNDEX value for both words is same, but I didn't asked for that. Here's my query:

```
{
  "query": {
  "nested": {
      "path": "skillName",
      "query": {
          "multi_match": {
              "query": "Developer",
              "fields": ["skillName.en"]
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your mapping using GET index-name/_mapping

your field "en" will be using [English analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) which has a stemmer token filter. It  creates root tokens for the word.

**Stemming**

Stemming is the process of reducing a word to its root form. This ensures variants of a word match during a search.

> For example, walking and walked can be stemmed to the same root word:
> walk. Once stemmed, an occurrence of either word would match the other
> in a search.

So you are getting both "development" and "developer" when searched for developer.
For not stemming match you need to perform search on field which doesn't have analyzer. If such field doesn't exist . You will have to update your mapping and create one

Comment: Yes, when I checked mapping for "skillName.en", I found out that it has english analyzer attached:
```
"en" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "english"
           }
```
Thanks!